# How does a "measurement of $\vec v\cdot\vec \sigma$" on two-qubit states work?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, bell-basis

[Michael A. Nielsen & Isaac L. Chuang, *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, 10th Anniversary Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107002176) p.113, Box 2.7 states that "if a measurement of $\vec v\cdot\vec\sigma$ is performed on both qubits [of $\psi:=\frac{|ab\rangle-|ba\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$ ] , then we can see that a result of $+1 (−1)$ on the first qubit implies a result of $−1 (+1)$ on the second qubit," where $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ are the eigenstates with eigenvalue $+1$ and $-1$ respectively of $\vec v\cdot\vec\sigma$ where $\vec v$ is a unit $R^3$ vector and $\vec\sigma$ is the vector for the $3$ Pauli matrices.

What does it mean precisely in terms of operator actions by
"a measurement of $\vec v\cdot\vec\sigma$ is performed on both qubits, then see a result of +1"? Is it the following?
$$\vec v\cdot\vec\sigma\otimes I\ |\psi\rangle = \frac{|ab\rangle+|ba\rangle}{\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that *both* parties get the +1 measurement result is calculated by
$$
\frac{1}{4}\langle\psi|(I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})\otimes (I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})|\psi\rangle
$$
where $|\psi\rangle$ is the state that you're measuring. This is because the projector onto the $+$ solution is
$$
\frac12(I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}).
$$

Similarly, if I wanted to know the probability of Alice getting +1 and Bob getting -1, I'd evaluate
$$
\frac{1}{4}\langle\psi|(I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})\otimes (I-\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})|\psi\rangle
$$

Now, what you're *really* interested in is the probability that both parties get different answers:
$$
\frac{1}{4}\langle\psi|(I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})\otimes (I-\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})|\psi\rangle+\frac{1}{4}\langle\psi|(I-\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})\otimes (I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})|\psi\rangle.
$$
If you expand this, it's the same as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\langle\psi|(I\otimes I-\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\otimes \vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})|\psi\rangle
$$
In other words, you're after the $-1$ outcome of the measurement $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\otimes \vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$.

Comment: Yes. The reason is that $\vec v\cdot\vec\sigma=|a\rangle\langle a|-|b\rangle\langle b|$ and $I=|a\rangle\langle a|+|b\rangle\langle b|$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then don't you think the phrase "a measurement of $\vec v\cdot\vec\sigma$" is incorrect? It should rather be "a measurement of $
\frac12(I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})$". Do you agree?

Comment: There are two different ways of defining a measurement. You can *either* use projectors, in which case you have to give all projectors: $\{|a\rangle\langle a|,|b\rangle\langle b|\}|$ *or*, you can specify an operator such as $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$. This implicitly defines the set of projectors as being the projectors onto the different eigenspaces. It is very common, for example, to say "perform a $Z$ measurement" because it's easier than talking about projecting onto the $|0\rangle/|1\rangle$ basis.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I understand the equivalence between these two forms of the operator. I have no objections to using operators composed of $\vec v$ and $\vec\sigma$ but to the required operator being $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$ rather than $\frac12(I+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})$. Do you agree that the correct operator should be the latter rather than the former?

Comment: I may still be misunderstanding you. In terms of defining a measurement, those two operators are the same because they have the same eigenbasis. So why complicate it with extra terms?

Comment: I am confused now. Are you saying so long as two operators have the same eigenvectors or eigenbasis, they are the same in defining a measurement regardless of their eigenvalues? In other words, so long as two operators commute, they represent the same measurement? Would you give a reference for this claim? Perhaps it is somewhere in this Nielson and Chuang book?

Comment: Well, the bit about commutation is not true - the sets of projectors can be different if there are repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, that is the claim I am making. It is effectively in Nielsen and Chuang, page 87 (in my version), section 2.2.5. It specifies an observable $M$ from which it extracts the eigenprojectors. Hence, observables with the same projectors define the same measurement.

Comment: This does not seem to gel with the definition in the book. What is the definition of the result of a measurement? Is it not Equation (2.110-2.113) which is the expected value of a measurement operator $M$? Now two distinct operators, though with the same eigenbasis, will give two distinct expectations therefore two distinct results. Do you agree?

Comment: The result of a single measurement (no repeats) is a single value corresponding to an eigenvalue of $M$ (but these are just labels, so I don't care if the label is "1" or "5" so long as it corresponds to the same eigenspace). Yes, if you repeat the measurement many times, the average you get is the expected value of the measurement operator, and the value of the labels will matter. It's up to you to define what quantity is actually important to you.